# Incomprehensible segfaults when working with SDL2 + SDL2pp wrapper

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sdl, wrapper

I'm learning SDL2, I'm enjoying it but I don't like C. So I felt it was useful to use a C++ wrapper ([this one](https://github.com/libSDL2pp/libSDL2pp)) in order to write a better code with C++ properties (so bad it's limited to C++11).

However, I am getting a major problem since the moment I decided to do serious things in SDL. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL2pp/SDL2pp.hh>
#include <SDL2pp/Texture.hh>
#include <SDL2pp/Font.hh>

int main()
{
    try {
        SDL2pp::SDL app(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
        SDL2pp::SDLImage sdl_image;
        SDL2pp::SDLMixer sdl_mixer;
        SDL2pp::SDLTTF sdl_ttf;

        SDL2pp::Window wdw("",
                           SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                           SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                           1280,
                           768,
                           SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
        wdw.Show();

        SDL2pp::Renderer rdr(wdw, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
======> SDL2pp::Texture txtr1(rdr, "prout.png"); // Where the code generally crashes. No callstack outside main().
        SDL2pp::Font fnt("font.ttf", 32);

        std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;

    } catch (SDL2pp::Exception& e){
        std::cout << "============= ERROR =============" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Function: " << e.GetSDLFunction() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.GetSDLError() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The SDL libraries are initialized as well, I can create a window, then a renderer... but it doesn't matter if I create a render loop or not, when I'm declaring a SDL Texture or Font object, **the window just crashes.**
After launching the debugger, this one just returns me "Segmentation fault" and points to the Texture declaration line - or if it's not there, the Font one - and... seems like Qt Creator is saying me "just deal with your own crap".

- I tried to check my CMakeLists.txt, no error to be found, either by me or Qt Creator.
- Reinstalled all my SDL libraries with pacman (I'm on Arch Linux btw)
- I sent a look into the wrapper code.. well it's just wrapper code, if it doesn't work, there's 95% chances the faulty one is SDL2 itself. And if possible, I would like to avoid using GDB on the whole SDL2 library.
- I noticed recently I wasn't able to compile SDL by myself, but since I'm using a library, I shouldn't be dependant of its compile-time dependances... right ?

Here is the callstack :  pastebin.com/9KyCRrMZ
I'm unable to find any solution, so thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Where in your code do you get the crashes? Please add a comment in the code, and preferably a full stack-trace. Can any of the SDL functions you use return with a failure (error code or null pointers)? Do you check for that?

Comment: I edited the first post. I'm using a wrapper, so I'm not using functions, as you can see, but no, I don't get any error or exception from the code. I really just have no idea of what the issue could be. The wrapper is supposed to manage errors for me. I can try C SDL code if you want, but I still don't get any error when I do it.

Comment: Just tried to check if the SDL window and renderer are initialized in C. Can now guarantee they are, no NULL value in their variables. but I evidently can't say for the texture and the font because the program crashes.

Comment: You *do* use functions. For example the `txtr1` definition uses the `SDL2pp::Texture` constructor function. And inside that function (or in its initializer list) other functions are used, directly or indirectly. If you catch the crash in a debugger, can you please print its stack-trace and copy-paste it into the question? The problem could be in the "wrapper" (well most likely is) and not in the code you currently show.

Comment: Do you mean this ? https://pastebin.com/9KyCRrMZ

Comment: That would be perfect, copy-pasted into the question itself. It shows that there's a likely problem in the `SDL2pp::Texture` constructor and its call to `IMG_LoadTexture`.

Comment: It seems like SDL could be the heart of the problem, as said in the first post. But then I don't know from what in the SDL creates this issue. I said I was unable to compile it because of a compilation error ; also, I launched a search about "IMG_LoadTexture" in the SDL2 repository, but I couldn't find anything. Strange, because the callstack now goes higher than this single function, implying it does really exist.

Comment: Ok, little update. I really feel like my version of the SDL is f***ed up for some obscure and probably stupid reasons but I can't compile it by myself from the Github source code. I literally tried to load a BMP file without any additional library, and it brought me the segfault. With a inexistant callstack (only main()). Damn it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, nevermind, it looks like I asked CMake to search the "SDL2" library, but then I tried to include the "SDL" librairies. No comment.

Kids, if you're dealing with a impossible-looking problem, always check your CMake.

Comment: I'd expect this to cause a compilation error, not a weird crash.